# Graphics row/case number showing

Tags: graphics

I want to draw scatter plot of two variables and showing the case number of on points of graph. and also multiple scatter graphs. Further these graphs are not disturbed on formatting their size. Dear please help how I plot these graphs in Mathematica.

Comment: Amin, please add sample data to your question and an example of what you want to achieve (could be a picture from a website, a sketch...). Also, what have you tried so far? Have you seen `ListPlot` and `Grid`?

Comment: Dear consider the data 
x = {5, 0.6, 0.35, 0.57, 0.88, 1.0};
y = {10, 3.5, 4.5, 7.8, 9.0, 12.2}; 
data = Transpose@{x, y};
I run the command
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 GridLines -> {{0.6}, {9}}]
Now I need the graph which showing observation/case number.
similar is done for multiple graphs using grid graphs
further when I copy these grid graph to Ms.Word, then image quality is poor. How I do for better graphs quality?

Comment: Amin, I am not sure if you just want this (copy and run): `ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[outputDir], "Directory"], 
   Dynamic[outputDir]}];
SetDirectory[outputDir];

x = {5, 0.6, 0.35, 0.57, 0.88, 1.0};
y = {10, 3.5, 4.5, 7.8, 9.0, 12.2};

data = Transpose@{x, y}; 

plot = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   GridLines -> {{0.6}, {9}}, Frame -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 40, 
     FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> 2000];


fileName = StringJoin[outputDir, "plot.png"];
Export[fileName, plot, "PNG"]`